# AppleScript: Using "whose" with record values does not work

Tags: macos, cocoa, applescript, cocoa-scripting

In my scriptable app, one of the properties is of a named record type, and that record type has been declared in the sdef as well (named "custom record").

I can get the record like this:

```
get owner of anElement
    --> {pool:"test", position:2}
```

I can also successfully test for it like this:

```
set target to {pool:"test", position:2}
if owner of anElement = target then
    -- found!
```

But I cannot use it in a whose clause:

```
get allElements whose owner = target
    --> {}
```

I also cannot use `missing value` in the test:

```
get allElements whose owner = missing value
    --> error number -1700 from missing value to custom record
```

Is that expected behavior with AppleScript, i.e. is it unable to handle records in whose clauses?

Or am I doing something wrong? I have so far not implemented any coercion handlers nor special record handlers because nothing has indicated that I'd need them.

Also, please see my related question: [Cocoa Scripting: Returning "null" vs. "missing value"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921259)

Answer (score 2):

Short answer : It's expected behavior.

The whose clause works only for `element` reference types (classes which have an object specifier), but not for record types and custom lists.

Even the `selection` property of the Finder cannot be filtered by a whose clause.

Comment: Ah, *only classes which have an object specifier* makes sense. I'll consider turning the record into individual properties then to make this easier to handle. It's only two items in the record. I thought using a record type would make it look cleaner in the dictionary, but that's not really necessary.

Comment: Actually OP's AS code should work, since he's applying a query to a one-to-many relationship (`allElements whose TEST`), not an array of records. The inability to do an equality test on a property containing a record is most likely due to Cocoa Scripting being a bit shoddy and failing to perform the `owner = {pool:"test", position:2}` test correctly. As to  `missing value` failing, OP should check his SDEF includes `<type type="missing value"/>` in the property's type declaration.

Comment: @foo whose clause doesn't work for record types due to the lack of an `NSScriptObjectSpecifier`. It's a fact.

Comment: @foo - On the "missing value" type. If I add that, with code "msng", it's still not working. I get the error "Can’t make missing value into type custom record." number -1700"

Comment: Also, please see my related question about null and "missing value": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921259

Comment: See `man 5 sdef`; the `owner` property should be defined as `<property name="owner" code="..."><type type="custom record"/><type type="missing value"/></property>`.

Comment: @foo, are you saying I can include TWO types in a single property declaration? The Sdef editor won't let me do that, BTW. Thanks for the pointer to the `man` for sdef - I had no idea that exists.

Comment: @foo - indeed, the man page says that I may use multiple types in a single element. That will prevent me from using the Sdef editor as it'll remove anything from the sdef it doesn't understand next time I save. But it's a step forward.